# How to write javascript code in response alongwith file bytes

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, response, outputstream

I have written code for downloading the file which runs automatically when the page is loaded. I want to perform some javascript functions in the page when page is loaded e.g on window load function.

Following is my code to write file Bytes in response how to write javascript in response too.

```
  try{
    data = exporter.getData(exportRoot);

    if(data==null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to Generate the Presentation file.");
    }
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=smartArt_presentation.pptx");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");

    str.write(data);
    str.flush();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    String msg = "Error : "+ e.getMessage() ;
    str.write(msg.getBytes());
    str.flush();

}
```

Comment: Did not get what you actually want. Please simply your desired objective.

Comment: Actually i want to xlose the browser window wheb the file is sent to the user using response

Comment: You can close the browser window from the page using javascript. Or do you want to send the close command from controller. If the first one, then please look up my reply in answer and if the second one, then please follow Sky's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assemble it as string like this: `str.write("javascript:alert('hello');");`

Answer (score 0):

Call window close after the ajax call and if the ajax call return success.
Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '.....'
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
           ..............
           window.close();              
        }
    });
```

Or call the ajax function in document load if you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
         ......
         ......
        });
});
```